# Modifiers cannot be applied to multi-user data- How to solve?

Tags: error

I have a lattice and a solidify modifier, and I cannot apply either of them, I receive the "Modifiers cannot be applied to multi-user data" error. I understand that it must have something to do with my lattice object, but how am I supposed to solve it?
Thank you.
[image]

Comment: to add to Crantisz' answer, you can't apply the modifier if the object shares the same mesh with other objects

Comment: It doesn't have to do with the lattice object, it is the main object with the modifiers. Obviously you have made a linked duplicate of it by using Alt+D instead of Shift+D, so there's one or more other objects using the same object data. Solution for this see the answer by @Crantisz or simply delete the other objects if they are no longer needed.

Comment: @moonboots Just thought the same ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press **Object** ⇾ **Relations** ⇾ **Make Single User** ⇾ **Object & Data**

Comment: Thank you for your comment(s). It was the most useful.  @moonboots

Comment: Thank you for your comment(s). It was the most useful.   @Gordon Brinkmann

Comment: Thank you for your comment(s). It was the most useful.   @Crantsiz