# Error: Modifiers cannot be applied to multi-user data- solving with python API

Tags: python, modifiers

Modifiers cannot be applied to multi-user data - how can I solve for complex deeply nested meshes via Python

I have looked at https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/253286/151885 is there a way to set this option in the API?

[This](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64076/error-modifier-cannot-be-applied-on-multi-user-data) seems to be a slightly different context than my issue, where I'm importing many gltf files via a headless script, whereas they're working in the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Apply modifier to multi-user

```
import bpy

def apply_md_by_name(name):
    try:
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier=name)
        return True
    except: # wrong name, modifier disabled, no data to apply, ...
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_remove(modifier=name)
        return False

def apply_md(obj, md_name):
    try:
        # set active object
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj

        # add a mesh to blend data
        temp = bpy.data.meshes.new("temp")

        # get users
        me = obj.data
        users = [o for o in bpy.data.objects if o.data == me and o != obj]

        for u in users:
            u.data = temp

        apply_md_by_name(md_name)

        for u in users:
            u.data = me

        bpy.data.meshes.remove(temp)
        del users
    except:
        print("    Fail")
        # not in object mode, wrong name, ...

apply_md(bpy.context.object, "Bevel")
```

Comment: you posted your answer twice. probably should remove the other answer.